# I am having problems with import nmap in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, nmap

I am trying to run  this piece of code in pycharm:

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

but without any success:

> import nmap   File "C:\Users\Hélder
>   Júnior\PycharmProjects\security\nmap.py", line 2, in 
>       nm = nmap.PortScanner() AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner

I tried to install the nmap libraries  via pycharm also via pip in cmd.

Answer (score 2):

You are clearly confusing two import styles here. You can either import the module, and then refer to the class using `modulename.ClassName()`

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

Or alias the imported module name, and then use the alias as `aliasName.ClassName()`

```
import nmap as nm
netmap = nm.PortScanner()
```

For more information, consider looking at the docs: https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/

Comment: Sorry, I tried :   nm = nmap.PortScanner()
AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'

Comment: You need to make sure the pip you are using to install nmap is tied to PyCharm's python interpreter, to verify that, just open the python interpreter for the pip you used to install the library, if the code works on the interpreter, link that interpreter to PyCharm, or find the interpreter tied to Pycharm and install there, if the code doesn't work, make sure you are using the correct pip to install the library! @HelderJúnior

Comment: In cmd I am getting the same error. AttributeError: module "nmap" has no attribute "portscanner"

Comment: Which python version are you using and which pip version did u use to install nmap?

Comment: I installed nmap via pip also in pycharm Packages, in pycharm I have nmap"0.0.1",nmap-vscan"1.1.0",pip"19.0.3",python-nmap"0.6.1",setuptools"40.8.0" installed...

Comment: my python is 3.7

Comment: Ohh got it, you should rename your file to something apart from nmap.py, `C:\Users\Hélder Júnior\PycharmProjects\security\nmap.py`, maybe `script.py`
Your filename is messing up with the library! @HelderJúnior

Comment: No you didn't get my point , change this file `C:\Users\Hélder Júnior\PycharmProjects\security\nmap.py"` to something other than `nmap.py`

Comment: makes sense, but : "C:\Users\Hélder Júnior\PycharmProjects\security\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Hélder Júnior/PycharmProjects/security/porta_scanner.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hélder Júnior/PycharmProjects/security/porta_scanner.py", line 3, in <module>
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a file named `nmap.py` anywhere in your project? @HelderJúnior

Comment: Also remove all `.pyc` files from your project @HelderJúnior

Comment: I will delete this projetct, and try to create a new one, just one second :)

Comment: Sure thing @HelderJúnior

Comment: Also run `pip uninstall nmap, pip uninstall python-nmap, pip install python-nmap` to uninstall `nmap` and reinstall `python-nmap` if creating a new project doesn't work @HelderJúnior

Comment: thanks a lot buddy, I created a new project and installed again python-nmap, and work.. thanks you help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`nm` is a variable, not a library. Your library is `nmap` so you should use `nmap.PortScanner()`

Use `nm = nmap.PortScanner()`

Answer (score 0):

First import, then use.

```
import nmap as nm
netmap= nm.PortScanner()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the reference of this package, your code is all right.

The problem could be related to those factors:

- You used `pip install python-nmap` and maybe inside PyCharm you are using another Python interpreter, not linked to the terminal pip.
- If you used PyCharm to install this package you need to be sure to use the interpreter in which you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously installed nmap, then first uninstall it and then reinstall again.

`pip uninstall nmap`

`pip install python-nmap`

This should help.